# How to develop MobileFirst shell component using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to understand on how to build a shell component native code on Android with `MFP 7.1` using Android Studio instead of ADT.

I got the `MyProject/components/ShellComponent/android/native` folder created after build the component, but there is no option to `Run As > Android Studio project`. I wanted to add Java classes to run under `src`. The ADT version uses a separate project tree, but with Android Studio, there is no separate tree.

I also tried to open native folder as an Android Studio project and it shows an empty project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the ShellDevelopment sample on Android Studio and it works fine.
Open the project in Eclipse -> Right Click on Android environment -> Run As -> Android Studio Project. When Android Studio is opened DON'T MIGRATE PROJECT TO GRADLE!

Anyway **it is not recommended**! if you want to make changes - use Eclipse to make these changes.